# Regex word-breaker in unicode

Tags: .net, regex, unicode, character-properties

How do I convert the regular expression 
\w+
To give me the whole words in Unicode – not just ASCII?

I use .net

Comment: which language? thai? :D

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, `\w` will match Unicode characters that are Unicode letters or digits.  For example, it would match `ì` and `Æ`.

To just match ASCII characters, you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected for me

```
        string foo = "Hola, la niña está gritando en alemán: Maüschen raus!";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\w+");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(foo);
        foreach (Match ma in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ma.Value);
        }
```

It outputs

```
Hola
la
niña
está
gritando
en
alemán
Maüschen
raus
```

Are you using .Match() instead of .Matches()?

Another possible explanation is that you have a non word character in what you expect to receive, like a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#ECMAScript 
There's also a nice Cheat Sheet for using regex in .net: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The "official" Unicode identifier for letters is `\p{L}`, for numbers `\p{N}`. So for completeness' sake, in cases where `\w` doesn't extend to Unicode letters/numbers, the equivalent for `\w+` would be `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Pc}]+`. Don't forget that the underscore and other "punctuation connector" characters are also contained in `\w` (so you can decide yourself whether to keep them or not).

Comment: For further completeness, `\w` includes not just underscore, but the entire `\p{Pc}` punctuation connector category :)